# packet that has been send in netbeans doesn't show up in wireshark nor cmd->netstat

Tags: java, tcp, client

I've been trying to send a tcp/ip packet from a simple client to a simple server...

I get response from the server when i run them in netbeans but i can't find the packet in wireshark and if i use the netstat command in cmd, the packet also doesn't seem to be there...
i've tried a few different ports (8080,80,5000,...) and as ip address i'm using localhost.

Is there some setting in netbeans or wireshark that i missed and i still need to configure?

The client:

```
public class TCPClient {

    private static InetAddress host;
    private static final int PORT=1235;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            host=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Host id not found");
            System.exit(1);

        }
        run();    

    }

    private static void run()
    {
        Socket link=null;
        try
        {
            link = new Socket(host,PORT);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true);

            BufferedReader userEntry = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String message,response;

           do
            {
                System.out.println("Enter message: ");
                message=userEntry.readLine();
                out.println(message);
                response=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("\nSERVER> " + response);               
            }
             while(!message.equals("***CLOSE***"));

        }
         catch(IOException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                  System.out.println("\n* Closing connection... *");

                  link.close();
            } 
            catch(IOException e)
            {
            System.out.println("unable to disconnect!");
            System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The server:

```
public class TCPServer {

    private static ServerSocket serverSock;
    private static final int PORT = 1235;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("opening port...\n");
        try
        {
            serverSock=new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("unable to attach port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        do
        {
            run();
        }
        while(true);

    }

    private static void run()
    {
        Socket link=null;
        try
        {
            link = serverSock.accept();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(),true);

            int numMessages=0;
            String message = in.readLine();

            while(!message.equals("***CLOSE***"))
            {
                System.out.println("Message received.");
                numMessages++;
                out.println("Message " + numMessages + ": " + message);
                message=in.readLine();
            }
            out.println(numMessages + " messages received");

        }
         catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("unable to disconnect!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to listen on the loopback interface, not your actual network interface in wireshark.

Comment: is there a simple way to do this on windows? lo doesn't show up between my list of interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to capture the packets. You can then use Wireshark to post-analyze the packets afterward or pipe the output to Wireshark using a method similar to the following ... assuming you have [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)'s [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) available::

**cmd1**: `RawCap.exe -f 127.0.0.1 localhost_capture.pcap`

**cmd2**: `tail -c +0 -f localhost_capture.pcap | Wireshark.exe -k -i -`

The **-f** switch tells RawCap to [flush](http://netresec.com/?b=11A24E0) each packet to disk directly rather than to buffer it. This makes sense when doing real time analysis with tail + Wireshark as in *cmd2* above; however it does come with a performance penalty, so use it with caution.